# wget exit code with -nc

Tags: bash, wget

If I try downloading a file which already exists with `wget` using the `--no-clobber` option, it works as expected but the exit code is `1` which is crashing my scripts. Why is the exit code `1` and how can I work around it?

```bsh
$ wget -nc --continue --output-document "/User/Downloads/download.txt" "https://example.com/download.txt"
File ‘/User/Downloads/download.txt’ already there; not retrieving.
$ echo $?
1
```

Comment: I would guess it's considered a failure, because the file could not be downloaded. As a work-around, you could rename the existing file and try again. Or don't use `-nc` and perform the check yourself.

Comment: interesting. I would actually consider this a bug.

Comment: Feel free to report it. See https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html#Reporting-Bugs.

Comment: reported. thanks.

Comment: What do you actually _mean_ when using `--continue` and `--no-clobber` together? On one hand, you want to continue a transfer, by on the other you don't want to modify the document if it exists?